# Overflow in recursive function

Tags: c++, recursion, overflow

So I was writing this exercise code that computes the maximum value of a vector using recursion and, for some reason, I'm getting overflow on the return statement.

Heres the code:

```
template<typename T>
T max_helper(vector<T> v, T max, int i){
    T m = v[i];
    cout << "Max: " << max << "\n";
    if (i < v.size()-1) {
        if (m > max) max_helper(v, m, ++i);
        else max_helper(v, max, ++i);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Max2: " << max;
        return max;
    }
}

template<typename T>
T maximum(vector<T> v){
    T max = max_helper(v, 0, 0);
    cout << "\nMax3: " << max;
    if (max > v[v.size()-1]) return max;
    else return v[v.size()-1];
}

int main() {
    int seed = static_cast<int>(time(0));
    srand(seed);
    vector<int> v(20);
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
        v[i] = 1+rand() % 100;
    }

    int r = maximum(v);
    cout << "\n";
    for (auto i: v) cout << i << " ";
    cout << "\nLargest element: " << r;

    return 0;
}
```

return statement:

```
Max: 97
Max2: 97
Max3: 6421696
5 19 24 9 85 78 59 1 15 31 36 54 13 19 80 84 56 42 97 21
Largest element: 6421696
```

any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Please turn on compiler warnings and read them. You're not returning the result of the recursive calls to `max_helper`.

Comment: Side notes: `v[v.size()-1]` -> `v.back()` if your compiler isn't an antique or compiling in antique mode. `i < v.size()-1` can fail hilariously because `v.size` is unsigned. If `i` is negative, it will warp around to a massive number. If `v` is empty, `v.size()-1` will also become a huge number.  [`rand` sucks](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful). Every change someone needs to make to your code to get a [mre] is an opportunity for them to accidentally fix the bug or inject a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case `i < v.size()-1)` is `true`, `max_helper` does not return any value so your program has undefined behavior.

You should return something. Example:

```
template<typename T>
T max_helper(vector<T> v, T max, int i){
    T m = v[i];
    cout << "Max: " << max << "\n";
    if (i < v.size()-1) {
        if (m > max) return max_helper(v, m, ++i); // return added
        else return max_helper(v, max, ++i);       // return added
    }
    else {
        cout << "Max2: " << max;
        return max;
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6ec71j)

Comment: didn't fix it, although thanks for the tip.
the problem is the return from max_helper to maximum. maximum is returning 97 (Max2 output line), but maximum is receiving 6421696 into the return variable (Max3 output line). I don't know where the heap corruption is coming from, tho

Comment: @barberchopz I added a demo where the only change I made to your original code was to add the `return`s. What's the result of my suggested change on your side?

Comment: i noticed and i implemented it. no changes, same output...

Comment: @barberchopz What compiler are you using? Are you running exactly the same code as I put in the godbolt demo?

Comment: apologies, didn't see the return right after the if! it working now. thank you very much :)

Comment: meanwhile, i thought the the final return would take care of it: by the time control reached the end of the vector it would return the maximum found value. this would mean the problem was the value transition inside the recursive function, right?

Comment: @barberchopz Every call, to any function - recursive or otherwise, must `return` what you declared that it will return. Otherwise your program will have undefined behavior.